# Connecting to bash existing container docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose for a project that has multiple services.

To run it, I simply type `docker-compose up` and `docker ps` would show a list of running services as follows:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                 PORTS                                                   NAMES
94cc0fca9ff5   backend_app             "sh entrypoint.sh /b…"   4 hours ago   Up 4 hours             0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp                                  backend_app_1
e770466bc28b   backend_worker          "sh entrypoint.sh /b…"   4 hours ago   Up 4 hours             3000/tcp                                                backend_worker_1
```

Till this point, I have no problem, all as expected. Now, I'm trying to run bash for the image backend_app. I tried:

1. `docker-compose exec app bash`
2. `docker exec -it backend_app /bin/bash`
3. `docker exec -it 94cc0fca9ff5 /bin/bash`

among a hundred other things, but none seem to work. What should I do to run bash when starting the image using docker-compose?

Comment: The third syntax look right; does it print an error?

Comment: What image does the `backend_app` run?  When you say "none seem to work", what _does_ happen?  If you weren't running the process in Docker, how would you get a shell inside that process?

Comment: Like Paolo said, the third syntax looks correct. Are you sure these images have `bash` installed on them? You might need to use `sh` instead: `docker exec -it 94cc0fca9ff5 sh`

Comment: This is correct @MrDiggles this actually worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the image you're using, bash might not be installed, should work 100% using sh instead.